# Type vs. class as dummy arguments

Tags: fortran

**First**) if you know that the type being passed to a procedure is not going to be extended should you use **type()** instead of **class()**?

Is there a performance difference?

**Next**) In the case of type-bound procedures, should the **passed object dummy argument** always be declared with **class()** and not **type()**?

Finally, in the case of this passed object, should an **intent attribute** be explicitly assigned or assumed? **intent(in)** or **intent(inout)**?

Comment: You should generally only ask one question per post. They are connected, but are important enough so they could be separate.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would use `type` dummy arguments if the type is not extensible.  It is much simpler and can be faster to work with non-polymorphic types. Of course, unless you require the type bound procedure, because:
2. Yes, that is a requirement. Type bound procedures require the passed argument to be polymorphic (`class`).
3. You should not assume implicitly any intent. It is best to set the right intent explicitly. Both combinations can be meaningful in different procedures.